# Python: appending dictionaries to a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

This is a simple code to create a list of dictionaries in Python, however the append function in the loop is creating a list instead of the list of dictionaries.

How can I append a dictionary to a list?

```
data = []
d = { "item1": None,
     "item2": None
     }

for i in range(3):
    d["item1"] = i+1
    d["item2"] = i+2
    data.append(d)

print "data = ", data
```

The output I am looking for is

```
d = [
            {
                "item1": 1,
                "item2": 2
            },        
            {
                "item1": 2,
                "item2": 3
            },        
            {
                "item1": 3,
                "item2": 4
            }
         ]
```

Comment: Dictionaries are mutable. Change `data.append(d)` to `data.append(d.copy())`

Comment: I am guessing your issue is that all the dictionaries in the list, have the vaue 3 and 4 at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only adding the reference to `d` into your `data` list, but the `d` reference never changes, hence when you change `d`'s value in the next iteration, previously added dictionaries in the list changes as well.

Try -

```
data = []
for i in range(3):
    d = {}
    d["item1"] = i+1
    d["item2"] = i+2
    data.append(d)
print "data = ", data
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply append new dictionary:

```
for i in range(3):
    data.append({"item1": i+1, "item2": i+2})
```

Or, even better, use list comprehension:

```
data = [{"item1": i+1, "item2": i+2} for i in range(3)]
```